# Variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' is a read only variable.

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL version 5.1.73

If I run `SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;`  I am getting following error

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1238 - Variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' is a read only variable
```

If I try to set this value in the mysql configuration file the mysql server is not restarting.

How to fix this?

Comment: Anything in the [error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)? Please also post your configuration line, there could be a syntax error.

Comment: @RandomSeed I just added innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120 in the configuration file